# CakePHP: routes and static pages

Tags: cakephp, routes

I am working on one small project - web site. There are gallery, user login, shop and many small text sections - with images and without.
   I want to make pretty urls for example:

```
Gallery -> /eng/gallery (GalleryController::index)
Gallery album /eng/gallery/album_name_slug (GalleryController::view)
Shop -> /eng/products (ProductsController::index)
Shop one product -> /eng/products/product_name_slug (ProductsController::view)
```

and all other (text) pages goes to "PagesController", but without /pages/view prefix

```
Contacts -> /eng/contacts
About us -> /eng/about_us
```

I thought that I can make something like this:

```
// Homepage
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'homepage', 'action' => 'display'));

/* There delegate routes for each controller/method (gallery, shop, etc) */

// All what is not in thease controllers/methods goes to pagescontroller
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view'));
```

What is the best way to make it in routes.php? Maybe you can give some generic example?

Thanks!

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with your routes. What's not working?

Comment: I want to know are there posibility, to get this working, not delegating all functional (products/gallery) routes, only with catch all?

Comment: what do you mean by "delegating all functional routes"?

Comment: Mmm... I badly made my question. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Gallery -> `/eng/gallery` (GalleryController::index) :

```
Router::connect('/eng/gallery', 
    array('controller' => 'gallery', 'action' => 'index'));
```

For Gallery album `/eng/gallery/album_name_slug` (GalleryController::view) :

```
Router::connect('/eng/gallery/:album', 
    array('controller' => 'gallery', 'action' => 'view'), 
    array('pass' => array('album'),'album' => '[0-9a-zA-Z]+') 
);
```

repeat for Products controller

Comment: There are no possibilities to use controllers and methods as default and only if no such controller/method go to pages controller? I am looking for DRY solution. Of course if there is no such, I will accept your answer!

Comment: My catchall consists of the following:
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));